# I can't put in order my tables and graphics on RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am using RMarkdown to write a paper for college. I have put in it some tables and graphics but they are not in order as I want, they  are not even under the right paragraph. Could someone tell me how to do?

Comment: You need to put together a small example showing the problem.  It should be self-contained; it doesn't need to be very big, just big enough to show us what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this for a PDF or HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

it's for a PDF file.
in the picture that  I've posted you can see that the graphic is after the tables even if in the chunck I made the graphic before the tables as I wanted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0HuK.png)